# Why does my array.IndexOf keep returning -1 (Visual Basic)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, indexof

I have a homework program for Visual basic. It stores 7 phone numbers for 7 friends in parallel arrays. I am using array.indexof to see if my input string is within the name array, then return the complete name and the corresponding number. I am not looking for the answer from posters, just some guidance or point out an over site on my part. Thanks in advance. sorry if my post is garbled or formatted incorrect, first time posting  Robert

```
  Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim strNames() As String = {"BILLY", "JILLY", "MILLY", "PHILLY", "LARRY", "CURLY", "MOE"}
    Dim strNumbers() As String = {"313-213-1234", "248-123-3452", "123-321-1234", "987-986-3456", "567-635-7632", "524-456-6782", "918-872-3452"}
    Dim strLookFor As String
    Dim found As Boolean


    strLookFor = InputBox("Type in the person you want to call", "Phone a Friend") 'prompt from user
    strLookFor.TrimEnd()  'trim whitespace after entry
    strLookFor = strLookFor.ToUpper  'convert to upper case to match

    txtResults.Clear() 'clear text box
    found = False  'set boolean to false
    intCounter = 0  'set intCounter to 0
    Do While Not found And intCounter < strNames.Length

        Dim intIndex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(strNames, strLookFor) 'SHOULD return a value of 0 or higher if found
        If intIndex >= 0 Then  'if loop for value of 0 or higher
            found = True
        End If

        intCounter += 1 'add 1 to intCounter

    Loop


    If found Then  'display phone match up results
        txtResults.Text = ((strNames(intCounter - 1)) & " " & (strNumbers(intCounter - 1)))
    Else
        txtResults.Text = ("Match not found.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it do or fail to do? Also, you've tagged this [vba] and VBA has no indexOf function. Can we assume you're using VB.net?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a dictionary(of string, string), its ideal for this type of thing:

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    dic.Add("BILLY", "123-456-888")
    dic.Add("JILLY", "333-555-222")
    dic.Add("MILLY", "777-334-667")
    dic.Add("PHILLY", "122-665-333")

    Dim strLookFor As String = InputBox("Type in the person you want to call", "Phone a Friend").ToUpper

    If dic.ContainsKey(strLookFor) Then
        MessageBox.Show(dic(strLookFor))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Match not found.")
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't want the answer, only hints, so here's mine:

You don't need a loop and you don't need `intCounter` or `found`.

`IndexOf` returns either -1, if there is no match, or the index of the element of the array if there is a match.

Comment: Array.IndexOf() doesnt need a loop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310891%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work this morning using a search array instead of array.indexof. sorry if it was posted incorrect, I'm running it on visual basic express. Thanks for the help people. The revision I made was (for future reference)
strNames (intCounter).IndexOf (strLookFor)

Comment: This is not a good solution. As mentioned by doug, you do not need to loop through the elements of an array to use IndexOf, strLookFor.TrimEnd() returns a new string you are not using (should be strLookFor = strLookFor.TrimEnd()), not to mention a dictionary would be much simpler :)

Comment: I agree with @user574632. -1 from me. This is a time to develop good habits :).